# Lightning RecordEditForm - getting error [object object] for few users

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-record-form

Problem: Many users are able to see a form but few users are not able to see the form and getting error `[object object]`.

I am using `lightning:recordEditForm` as below in lightning record page:

```
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="form" recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                                          objectApiName="{!v.objectName}"
                                          onerror="{!c.handleFormError}"
                                          onsuccess="{!c.handleFormSuccess}">
                    <!-- the messages component is for error messages -->
                    <lightning:messages />

     // lightning:inputField
```

While testing for different users, its working for most of the users but failing for very few users and getting UI like below:

[image]

When trying to debug (with breakpoint) the `event` from method `handleFormError`, I am getting below in console logs

> ```
> event.getParam('message')
> "Cannot read property 'errorCode' of undefined"
>
> event.getParam('detail')
> ""
>
> event.getParam("output").fieldErrors
> undefined
>
> JSON.stringify(event.getParam('output'))
> "{}"
>
> JSON.stringify(event.getParam('error'))
> "{"ok":false,"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request","body":{}}"
> ```

---

Further, I am getting below error in console log after the record page is loaded.

> KB {component: "markup://force:lds", componentStack:
>   "[lightning:recordEditForm]", action: null, name: "AuraFriendlyError",
>   message: "Error in fetching record or record metadata. [[object
>   Object]]", …}

For the user, for his profile, all the fields used in form have `editable` permission for that specific record type and has access to record. App is normal (non-console). Object is Opportunity (and its custom fields).

PS: Pls let me know if any other info has to be added in question. Thanks in advance!

**----------------------- EDITED ---------------------------------------**

Event for very simple form like below, I am getting error for this user:

```
<lightning:recordEditForm recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                              objectApiName="Opportunity">
        <lightning:messages />

        <lightning:outputField fieldName="Name" />
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Comment: Can you add more details like user licence type? is it communites? Is it for all objects or just standard object? `objectApiName` is dynamic , is it possible for it to be wrong , or someone prvided wrong input?

Comment: Its `Opportunity`, and normal app (added in question). While loading in read/view mode itself, getting this error.

Comment: I feel it's related to some fields? Can you just have a single field `Name` in input and see if it works?

Comment: More like, user have access to those field(lookup), but no access to the lookup object /record.

Comment: It's actually just date time fields. But I will try that and see. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: @PranayJaiswal even for simple form (added in question) i am getting error - ever faced such problem?

Comment: Looks very weird, cant see any mention of this behaviour even in known issue site. You might have to raise a case with SF support. Is it sandbox btw? Might be ghost records my last guess

Comment: In all objects facing error - looks like user does not have access to recrd edit form

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you kept all the fields on the layout which you have referred in your lightning component. It was working for me.