# Record edit form not accessible by a user

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-recordeditform

This question is the extension of  [THIS](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/273172/lightning-recordeditform-getting-error-object-object-for-few-users?noredirect=1#comment412367_273172)  question. Posting again (with simplified code) as I am blocked in this issue.

Even for very simple form as below I am getting [object object] error.

```
<lightning:recordEditForm recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                          objectApiName="Opportunity">
    <lightning:messages />

    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Name" />
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

[image]

This user has access to record, to field (editable ofcourse) and the field is on page layout.

Any other checks/directions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anybody faces this error, here is what we found and fixed the error.

1. Created clone of that profile.
2. Gave `Modify all data` and `View all data` permissions (thereby enabling dependent permissions).
3. Then the user was not getting any error.
4. Then again removed all the new permissions enabled including `Modify all data` and `View all data` to make this profile exactly same as old one (from which cloned).
5. Now User has no problem and able to view data and error is gone.

This appears to be a sandbox specific bug (awfully strange bug though).

Answer (score 1):

I face this same error and while debugging a lot i found the issue was in my apex code. My page layout assignment which i queries through tooling api was incorrect. Seems tooling api query doesn't work properly through lightning components. I raised a case to Salesforce for this.

Lightning Record edit forms are very strange - This same issue was there in my dev environment but there this error was not thrown.